# Symfony2 return response of an action in another action to JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, forms, symfony, entity

In my application I have an feature that needs to reload whole form on an a update action. I thought I can just make an AJAX request to special action and in that action call the original action that generate the form but based on diffrent parameters.

How can I respond to JavaScript request with an HTML output of diffrent action?

I've tried something like this:

```
if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
    return $this->editPageContentAction($responseObjects[0]->getId());
}
```

but it does not work (Controller must return response).

The easiest way to describe what I want to achive is:

- I have a form that edits an entity with a select "copy content from another entity" with list of other enteties
- When user selects another entity I want to reload with AJAX the form Im currently on but populated with selected Entity
- I dont want to redirect user to edit entity form with selected entity, I want to just prefill new entity form with data from existing entity, so I though I could use action that allready exists to editing this entity.
- Javascript function will just update the html with new form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
    return new Response($this->editPageContentAction($responseObjects[0]->getId()));
}
```

When your editPageContentAction method return the html output.